# How to get doc sets installed in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode5

i just upgraded to Xcode 5, the document function now is different from the old version of xcode (there's no longer document tab in preferences). In Xcode 5, i go to Preferences->download tab , then i download all updated doc sets. And in ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode I find seem to be the corresponding dmg's:

> com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS7.0.iOSLibrary-44.17.dmg
>   com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleXcode.DeveloperTools-511.16
>   com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleOSX10_8.CoreReference-419.37.dmg

I don't know that whether Xcode will automatically install these dmg files or only download them and i have to install these files manually? And where in xcode i have to go to check if a new document is installed or not? Thank for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hold [option] and move your cursor on a function name, when your cursor change to a question mark, click it, and Xcode directs to the documents

**UPDATE**

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

It seems Xcode installed the docs, but did not remove them.
You can check `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets` folder, the older docs are still existing.

[image]

Comment: Yes i knew that, but how can i know that it is a new version of document or the old version? Because i only installed new version but never removed the old version.

Comment: In Preferences -> Downloads -> Documentation, a little download button you can click, after downloading Xcode will automatically install the doc. When installing, Xcode display the installation progress in top progress bar, which displays building progress. If it finished installing, Preferences -> Downloads -> Documentation show a tick icon .

Comment: i did exactly the same, but it seems to be xcode only download doc set but not install them right? do you know how to remove the installed doc set?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can check your DocSets folder to make sure if Xcode have installed successfully and removed the older.

Answer (score 6):

After downloading the dmg file of iOS 7.1 from the following source:
[iOS 7.1 doc set](http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/20140311/031-1467-A.dmg).

I executed the .pkg file and the installer put the `"com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS7.1.iOSLibrary.docset"` file in the root of `"Macintosh HD"`.
Then I moved the docset file to the following location
`"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets"`

and it works like a charm.

PS: Xcode doesn't put a tick near the iOS 7.1 doc in the documentation list, however it works.

Comment: Works great with iOS 8.1 as well :)